# Return base class in LINQ for stored procedure causes stackoverflow

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, inheritance, stack-overflow

I have quite complex SP which returns base class (basecontent). I have inheritence with about 30+ child classes (like "page", "news", etc).

When I return other types from SP everything works fine, but this one drives me crazy. I am quite experienced with LINQ and already tryied to recreate SP, verified outout, etc. 
But this call fails to Stackoverflow exception even when number of returning rows is zero.

I have workaround - when I join it with another table, which has some statistics about content and do not have any inheritance, than I am able to go to content table using C# and take data, but this is significant performance degradation for me.

So far, my main guess is that something wrong with my inheritance mapping. Here is xml for this class:

```
<Table Name="dbo.baseContent" Member="baseContents">
    <Type Name="baseContent" Id="ID50" InheritanceCode="1" IsInheritanceDefault="true">
      <Column Name="Id" Type="System.Int64" DbType="BigInt NOT NULL IDENTITY" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsDbGenerated="true" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="Type" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" IsDiscriminator="true" />
      <Column Name="Status" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="UniqueId" Type="System.Guid" DbType="UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="LastChanged" Member="LastChangedUTC" Storage="_LastChanged" Type="System.DateTime" DbType="DateTime NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" UpdateCheck="Never" />
      <Column Name="Title" Modifier="Virtual" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(255) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="Version" Type="System.Int64" DbType="Bigint" CanBeNull="true" UpdateCheck="Never" />
      <Column Name="Tags" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarchar(255)" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="baseOwnerId" Type="System.Int64" DbType="BigInt NOT NULL" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="Views" Type="System.Int32" DbType="int" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="VotesValue" Type="System.Int32" DbType="int" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="Clicks" Type="System.Int32" DbType="int" CanBeNull="true" UpdateCheck="Never" />
      <Column Name="IsHidden" Type="System.Boolean" DbType="bit" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="IsFeatured" Type="System.Boolean" DbType="bit" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="IsAdvertising" Type="System.Boolean" DbType="bit" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="LoyaltyPoints" Type="System.Int32" DbType="int" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="CreatedDate" Type="System.DateTime" DbType="datetime" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="ViewsDetails" Type="System.Int32" DbType="int" CanBeNull="true" UpdateCheck="Never" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_baseDictionary" Member="baseDictionary" Storage="_baseDictionaries" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="baseDictionary" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tTopic" Member="tTopic" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="tTopic" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_baseFile" Member="baseFile" Storage="_baseFiles" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="baseFile" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tLink" Member="tLink" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="tLink" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tNews" Member="tNews" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="tNews" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tModule" Member="tModule" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="tModule" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tPage" Member="tPage" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="tPage" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tOwner" Member="tOwner" Storage="_tOwners" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="tOwner" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tMessage" Member="tMessage" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="tMessage" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tTheme" Member="tTheme" Storage="_tTemplates" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="tTheme" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_Tags_baseContent" Member="Tags_baseContents" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="Tags_baseContent" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tGoodie" Member="tGoodie" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="tGoodie" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tModuleSkin" Member="tModuleSkin" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="tModuleSkin" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tLocation" Member="tLocation" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="tLocation" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tEvent" Member="tEvent" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="tEvent" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tThread" Member="tThread" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="tThread" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tThread1" Member="RelatedThreads" Storage="_RelatedThread" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="RelatedContentId" Type="tThread" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_ContentVisit" Member="ContentVisit" Storage="_ContentVisits" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="ContentVisit" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="baseContent_tThreadAnswer" Member="tThreadAnswer" ThisKey="Id" OtherKey="ContentId" Type="tThreadAnswer" Cardinality="One" />
      <Type Name="baseRole" Id="ID51" InheritanceCode="2" />
      <Type Name="baseFolder" Id="ID52" InheritanceCode="3" />
      <Type Name="TopicContent" Id="ID53" InheritanceCode="5" />
      <Type Name="TopicPageContent" Id="ID54" InheritanceCode="6" />
      <Type Name="baseDictionaryContent" Id="ID55" InheritanceCode="7" />
      <Type Name="FileContent" Id="ID56" InheritanceCode="8" />
      <Type Name="TopicPlaceholderContent" Id="ID57" InheritanceCode="9" />
      <Type Name="TopicModuleContent" Id="ID58" InheritanceCode="10" />
      <Type Name="TopicLinkContent" Id="ID59" InheritanceCode="11" />
      <Type Name="TopicPageLayoutContent" Id="ID60" InheritanceCode="12" />
      <Type Name="TopicThemeContent" Id="ID61" InheritanceCode="13" />
      <Type Name="TopicNewsContent" Id="ID62" InheritanceCode="14" />
      <Type Name="TopicMessageContent" Id="ID63" InheritanceCode="15" />
      <Type Name="TopicOfferContent" Id="ID64" InheritanceCode="16" />
      <Type Name="TopicVoteUpContent" Id="ID65" InheritanceCode="17" />
      <Type Name="TopicVoteDownContent" Id="ID66" InheritanceCode="18" />
      <Type Name="TopicOwnerContent" Id="ID67" InheritanceCode="19" />
      <Type Name="TopicModuleTypeContent" Id="ID68" InheritanceCode="20" />
      <Type Name="TopicContainerTypeContent" Id="ID69" InheritanceCode="21" />
      <Type Name="TopicLanguageContent" Id="ID70" InheritanceCode="22" />
      <Type Name="TopicGoodieContent" Id="ID71" InheritanceCode="23" />
      <Type Name="TopicModuleSkinContent" Id="ID72" InheritanceCode="24" />
      <Type Name="TopicEventContent" Id="ID73" InheritanceCode="25" />
      <Type Name="TopicLocationContent" Id="ID74" InheritanceCode="26" />
      <Type Name="AbstractContentItem" Id="ID75" InheritanceCode="10000" />
      <Type Name="TopicThreadContent" Id="ID76" InheritanceCode="27" />
      <Type Name="TopicThreadAnswerContent" Id="ID77" InheritanceCode="28" />
      <Type Name="NavigationInfoContent" Id="ID78" InheritanceCode="29" />
      <Type Name="TopicViewContent" Id="ID79" InheritanceCode="30" />
      <Type Name="VisitedContent" Id="ID80" InheritanceCode="31" />
    </Type>
  </Table>
```

Here is declaration for SP:

```
<Function Name="dbo.SearchAdvanced" Method="SearchAdvanced">
    <Parameter Name="searchTerm" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(4000)" />
    <Parameter Name="searchKeywords" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(4000)" />
    <Parameter Name="searchType" Type="System.Int64" DbType="BigInt" />
    <Parameter Name="searchTreeType" Type="System.Int64" DbType="BigInt" />
    <Parameter Name="parentList" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" />
    <Parameter Name="filterList" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" />
    <Parameter Name="filterValue" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" />
    <Parameter Name="filterLessList" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" />
    <Parameter Name="filterLessValue" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" />
    <Parameter Name="filterGreaterList" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" />
    <Parameter Name="filterGreaterValue" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" />
    <Parameter Name="LCID" Parameter="lCID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
    <Parameter Name="minLevels" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
    <Parameter Name="Levels" Parameter="levels" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
    <Parameter Name="pageSize" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
    <Parameter Name="PageNumber" Parameter="pageNumber" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
    <Parameter Name="sortOrder" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
    <Parameter Name="TopicContentId" Parameter="topicContentId" Type="System.Int64" DbType="BigInt" />
    <Parameter Name="totalRows" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" Direction="InOut" />
    <ElementType IdRef="ID50" />
  </Function>
```

Comment: Still the issue. We recreated linq diagram, and when we added 13 inheritance, we get issue again. (any 12 works fine).
We found a way to trace linq - nothing interesting, just call to stored procedure.
Also we not able to stop on breakpoint in any of constructors on business objects. SO, error is somewhere inside linq.

Comment: Do you get the same exception if the search returns no results?  If not, does the exception happen whenever there are any results, no matter what the search parameters are?  Finally, do any of the classes in that hierarchy (including `baseContent`) have any custom code, i.e. defined in a partial class somewhere?

Comment: Exception happens even when 0 rows returned. We have some custom code, but it is ot get to point when object is instantiated. 
But I will double check, just in case

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to re-test with the VS2010 beta? There is, IIRC, a bug with one of the `IQueryable<T>` implementations re base-classes that is fixed in 4.0. You might find it works in 4.0, and then the question becomes: wait until April?

Comment: Not bad idea, but we need to release nearest weeks. I also read about this bug at msdn community.

Comment: @Sergey - well, you should perhaps at least assess whether it is the same issue; that may impact your long-term strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Just use standard fault finding techniques - halve and check

Edit SP to only have first half of paramters, adjust mapping to same. No problem - try other half.  Still have problem, halve again unti you find what is causing it

Comment: We did this - dbml was recreated from scratch, and we start to get exception back when adding 13th derived class :)
Only solution for now was not to use inheritance in linq.